# Identify this bone found on beach

Tags: species-identification, zoology, bone-biology

Does anyone have an idea what this bone is?

It was found on the beach in the Outer Banks, North Carolina, USA.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show another angle or two? I think I know what it is, but would like to see the whole thing. I can only guess right now.

Comment: Im sorry having issues posting additional pictures on site.  I did take more though…. Ill work on figuring posting.

Comment: Imgur, our image repository doesn't seem to work well with Amazon shared photos, you can however upload direct to imgur from your phone/desktop through the question interface, that works best.

Comment: @anongoodnurse are you able to see the photos I posted?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. All I see are bare links — one of the requirements for posts on this site is that they are self-contained. That means (among other things) that all photos must be uploaded to the site. Is there some reason you aren't able to follow the suggestion made by A Rogue Ant?

Comment: I think they are working now.  Will only allow me to post 2.

Comment: Great! You can add supplementary links to your post for the other pictures — it is just important that users don't have to leave the site to understand the question. (I see that I worded that unclearly before, sorry about any confusion.)

Comment: maybe a skate synarcual but that is a wild guess.

Comment: On the second pic i can see cellular structures in the well focused zone, I wonder if they give an idea of the family of the animal.